# nodejs + aws elasticache redis connection timed out

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, redis, amazon-vpc

I am using **redis 4.0.0** in my NodeJS AWS Lambda function to connect to a aws redis cluster.
I get a connection timed out. What am I doing wrong?

```js
    const redisUrl = 'redis://xyz.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379';
    const redisClient = redis.createClient({ url: redisUrl });
    await redisClient.connect();
```

`xyz.use1.cache.amazonaws.com` is the primary-endpoint of the cluster

Comment: Does the JS code execute on frontend or backend?

Comment: Backend. In a AWS lambda function. @Marcin

Comment: You have to provide all network related settings for the redis and your function.